# Pasting columns from different Worksheets into one

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am stuck with the following problem and need some help:
I am trying to paste the first column of every excelfile of a folder into one excelsheet so that the first column is in column A and the second in column B and so on. The columns are always in the first sheet in every workbook.

Here is what i have right now:

```
Sub OpenFiles()
Const FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\"
Dim MyFile As String
Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
Dim c As Integer
Dim destWb As Workbook


c = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MyFile = Dir$(FILE_PATH & "*.xlsx")
Set destWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Translations.xlsx")
Do Until MyFile = ""
    Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FILE_PATH & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=3)
    objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A100").Copy _
    destWb.Worksheets(1).Range(destWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, c)).Paste

    c = c + 1
    Call objWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
    MyFile = Dir$
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

it can't figure out how to copy and paste from the one Workbook to the other

Thanks for your help,

Valentin

Comment: Did you try using debugger ? The logic of your code sound good to me...
Maybe add `Debug.print c` so you can see if c value change as excepted

Comment: I would suggest you moving 'Set destWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Translations.xlsx")` above `MyFile = Dir$(...` and calculate `c` for each iteration: `c = destWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1`.

Comment: I tried to make your changes but the same error still occurs
The error message states: Runtimeerror 1004: 
runtime error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error
With the following line marked: 
objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A100").Copy _
            destWb.Worksheets(1).Range(destWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, c)).Paste

Thanks already for both of your suggestions. 
Sadly i do not know how to fix the error.

Comment: Did you follow my suggestion to define `c` variable prior to this line? If yes, when the code stops on error, moving the cursor over `c`, what value do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your vba script and modified a bit to test on my pc. Copy and paste often cause error. And your script `destWb.Worksheets(1).Range(destWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, c)).Paste` looks buggy. Here is my modified script that works perfectly.

```
Sub OpenFiles()
Const FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\***\Desktop\vba_test\"
Dim MyFile As String
Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
Dim c As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim destWb As Workbook


c = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MyFile = Dir$(FILE_PATH & "*.xlsx")
Set destWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\***\Desktop\dest.xlsx")
Do Until MyFile = ""
    Set objWb = Workbooks.Open(FILE_PATH & MyFile, True, True)
    For i = 1 To 20
        destWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, c).Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = objWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value
    Next i
    c = c + 1
    Call objWb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
    Set objWb = Nothing
    MyFile = Dir$
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Picklu, thanks you so much for your help. 
The script works perfectly :)